# Should glVertexPointer contain distinct vertices, or all vertices?

Tags: opengl-es

I'm creating an Android app utilising OpenGL ES, and need some help with the vertex, texture and normal pointers.  The examples I've seen stop at a fairly basic level so I seem to be missing a bit of information.

My basic draw() process is

```
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, uvBuffer);
gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, faceBufferLength, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, faceBuffer);
```

The vertex and uv are FloatBuffers constructed from the various x, y and z coordinates of the respective vertices and uv's.

The `faceBuffer` is a ByteBuffer of indices pointing to the relevant vertexBuffer.

Each face consists of three vertices, and each face defines a *different* UV for it's vertices (correct?)

My question therefore is, do I need to re-define each distinct vertex/uv combination in all the buffers?

Consider a simple tetrahedron.  It consists of

4 vertices (three 'base' and one 'point'):

```
Vertex 1: <1,1,1> (the point)
Vertex 2: <2,1,0>
Vertex 3: <0,0,0>
Vertex 4: <2,0,0>
```

3 uv coordinates (all faces have the same image)

```
UV 1: <0,0,0> (top left)
UV 2: <0,1,0> (bottom left)
UV 3: <1,0,0> (top right)
```

4 faces:

```
Face 1: v1/u1, v2/u2, v3/u3
Face 2: v1/u1, v3/u2, v4/u3
Face 3: v1/u1, v4/u2, v2/u3
Face 4: v2/u1, v3/u2, v4/u3
```

So my question is, how do I tell GL which UV to use for each face/vertex?

Should `vertexBuffer` have 4 sets of values in it, or 12?  Must `uvBuffer` and `vertexBuffer` have the same number of items?

Basically, can I "re-use" vertices if they have different UV and/or normal values?

Or do I have to be unique:

```
Vertex  1: <1,1,1> (face A)
Vertex  2: <2,1,0> (face A)
Vertex  3: <0,0,0> (face A)
Vertex  4: <1,1,1> (face B)
Vertex  5: <0,0,0> (face B)
Vertex  6: <2,0,0> (face B)
Vertex  7: <1,1,1> (face C)
Vertex  8: <2,0,0> (face C)
Vertex  9: <2,1,0> (face C)
Vertex 10: <2,1,0> (face D)
Vertex 11: <0,0,0> (face D)
Vertex 12: <2,0,0> (face D)

UV  1: <0,0,0> (face A)
UV  2: <0,1,0> (face A)
UV  3: <1,0,0> (face A)
UV  4: <0,0,0> (face B)
UV  5: <0,1,0> (face B)
UV  6: <1,0,0> (face B)
UV  7: <0,0,0> (face C)
UV  8: <0,1,0> (face C)
UV  9: <1,0,0> (face C)
UV 10: <0,0,0> (face D)
UV 11: <0,1,0> (face D)
UV 12: <1,0,0> (face D)

Face 1: v1/u1, v2/u2, v3/u3
Face 2: v4/u5, v5/u5, v6/u6
Face 3: v7/u7, v8/u8, v9/u9
Face 4: v10/u10, v11/u11, v12/u12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate the position data, as in have 12 vertex positions in vertexData. Do the same for the texture coordinates.

The indices, as you noticed, index *all* the arrays with the same indices, so it is standard to duplicate the vertex positions so that each index has its own vertex data (position + UV).

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer!  It's not a big problem to "expand" the identifiers into repeated vertices I suppose, I just thought it best to check that I'm not missing an obvious feature somewhere.